# Running mpirun with 2 cores/4 threads

Tags: python, mpi

I am using mpirun to call an openMDAO code that uses a parallel group which contains 4 subsystems. I can successfully call the code from the terminal as follows.

```
mpirun -n 2 python modified_objective.py
```

However since my pc has 2 cores/ 4 threads, I want to use all 4 threads to speed up my code. But i get an error as follows:

> There are not enough slots available in the system to satisfy the 4 slots
>   that were requested by the application:
>     python .
>     Either request fewer slots for your application, or make more slots 
>     available for use.

One of the work around I found online is to use a text rankfile as follows:

```
rank 0=localhost slot=0:0
rank 1=localhost slot=0:0
rank 2=localhost slot=0:1
rank 3=localhost slot=0:1
```

and then call the code as follows:

```
mpiexec -np 4 -H localhost -rf rankfile python modified_objective.py
```

But this does not seem to work. Is there another way I can use all 4 cores?

Thank you

Comment: If you use Open MPI, try `mpirun  --use-hwthread-cpus ...` in order to have 1 thread = 1 slot (the default is 1 core = 1 slot).

Answer (score 0):

The solution depends on the specific MPI implementation you have. Its not an OpenMDAO problem at all, but rather a problem with your MPI library. You seem to have seen that already, because you're trying to provide a host file.

I think you just have the wrong option though. Try:

```
mpiexec -np 4 -H localhost --hostfile rankfile python modified_objective.py
```